# Pointer) Is there a chance where (ptr + 1) is already occupied?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

```
char data;
char *ptr = &data;
*ptr = 3;
*(ptr+1) = 5;
```

So I am studying pointer, and one thing I quite don't understand.

When you use pointer as an array, how do you know address `ptr+1` or `ptr+2` and so on is not being occupied by some other variable?

So for example the address `ptr + 1` is already being used, and if I try to put 5 in it, is there a chance the program just crashes?

Or more extreme example something like `ptr + 1000`?

Or does the compiler make sure that it never happens?

Comment: You know because you're the one writing the code and you should know what your pointers point to, and how many. Sorry if that sounds snarky, but its the reality of programming in C (which I assume you're asking about, regardless of the questionable additional c++ tag). The compiler doesn't make sure of anything except to produce code as well-founded (or not) as the source form which it was birthed. In the given code `*(ptr+1) = 5;` invokes *undefined behavior*, and it's up to you *not* to do that.

Comment: There's a chance the program crashes, but the more likely outcome is worse:  silently corrupt memory and you'll just get a wrong result without any warning that something went wrong

Comment: If you're *lucky* the program crashes. That, at least, is resolvable. Regardless, as-is it's UB, which has a propensity of rearing ill-fate at the least opportune of times. I.e. it doesn't crash for you, but mysteriously it crashes on your professors rig when they run it. Or worse, a *paying customers environment*. Putting it simply, that's why we don't make it a habit of writing bad code.

Comment: @WhozCraig So are you saying that every program written in C has a very slight chance of bug because of the use of pointers? Edit) You are saying that it's the programmers job to make sure those slight chance doesn't exist am I right?

Comment: You can invoke *undefined behavior* in *many* ways in a C program; Illegitimate pointer usage is just one of them. It's the programmers job, on top of accomplishing their application task, to ensure they do so whilst staying in the confines of formally defined behavior as dictated by the langauge standard and tool chain they're utilizing to do it. It isn't just about spewing code; it's about writing *good* code.

Comment: @MattYoon: No, “use of pointers” is not a problem. “Improper use of pointers” is a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, now I fully understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition `char data;` reserves space for one `char`.

`char *ptr = &data;` sets `ptr` to point to that `char`.

The space at `ptr+1` is **not** reserved for your use, and neither the C nor the C++ standards define what happens if you try to use it.

The definition `char data[3];` would reserve space for three `char`. Then `char *ptr = data;` would set `ptr` to point to the first of these `char`. That is, `ptr` would have the address `&data[0]`, and `*ptr` would be `data[0]`.

Then `ptr+1` would point to the next `char`; it would have the address `&data[1]`, and `*(ptr+1)` would be `data[1]`.

Generally, you should use pointer arithmetic **only** to access space that you know is reserved for your use. (There may be exceptions or clarifications to that in special-purpose code, such as code in the operating system kernel to deal with memory mapping or code in special-purpose hardware. You do not need to consider such possibilities in normal user programs.)

The compiler generally does not prevent you from accessing invalid addresses. It might, in some circumstances, where it detects a reference out of bounds. Generally, this only happens in current compilers with simple expressions where the full definitions are visible to the compiler and the references essentially use constant indices.

The operating system may prevent you from accessing some invalid addresses. However, it will only prevent you from accessing invalid addresses either because they are not mapped to your program at all or they are mapped to be read-only but you tried writing to them (or certain other combinations, such as attempting to read execute-only memory). The operating system will not prevent you from accessing addresses improperly that are mapped and accessible to your program. For example, calculating an improper pointer value and using it in an assignment to change memory can result in changing data your program needs for other functions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't know if they are occupied by other variables or not.

This is undefined behavior, which means that the C standard does not specify what your program does. It could appear to "work", it could crash, it could give wrong results, or it could do anything else.

So don't do this.